# Read string with comma and insert into sql table single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table

```
Column A        Column B        Column C
----------------------------------------------
```

I have an input string like (Apple,Banana,Orange). I need to insert these values to the above table.

Result should be like

```
ColumnA     Column B        Column C
-------------------------------------------
Apple       Banana          Orange
```

Is it possible using a procedure that takes the input parameter as a csv string?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but it's a **bad** idea.

Comment: How? In my case this is the only possible way...

Comment: Why can't you just send 3 different parameters to the stored procedure?

Comment: Or import the csv into a temporary table, validate it the way you want (e.g. csv had 3 columns everywhere, no NULLs or repeated rows, etc) and copy over the records to the final table (indexed, etc) and drop the temp. one

Comment: Bcoz in future no of fields may increase, so I can update it within stored procedure, no need to touch the front end.

Comment: Than's not a good enough reason. If you want to make changes to the database without the need to change the front end you should add another layer between them.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below code to get the list of column name. You can pass the same to SP for inserting to your table.

```
BEGIN
          DECLARE @str VARCHAR(2000)
          DECLARE @input VARCHAR(4000)
          DECLARE @ind Int
          DECLARE @Count int 
          DECLARE @max int 
          SET @max =0
          DECLARE @table TABLE(ColumnA varchar(10),ColumnB varchar(10),ColumnC varchar(10))
          DECLARE @Result TABLE (ID int identity(1,1),value varchar(1000))
          SET @input ='Apple,Banana,Orange'
          IF(@input is not null)
              BEGIN
                    SET @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)
                    WHILE @ind > 0
                        BEGIN
                              SET @str = SUBSTRING(@input,1,@ind-1)
                              SET @input = SUBSTRING(@input,@ind+1,LEN(@input)-@ind)
                              INSERT INTO @Result values (@str)
                              SET @ind = CharIndex(',',@input)
                        END
              SET @str = @input
              INSERT INTO @Result values (@str)
             END

          SET @Count = (SELECT Max(ID) from @Result)

             WHILE @Count > @max
              BEGIN
               SET @max = @max +1
               DECLARE @Value varchar(1000)
               SET @Value = (SELECT value from @Result WHERE ID =@max)

               SELECT @value
             END
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check following SQL script which splits input string parameter and inserts into a table

Please note that I use [SQL split string function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx) dbo.Split and you can find the source codes at referred SQL tutorial

You will need such a user defined split function unless you use SQL Server 2016

```
/*
create table TableT (
[Column A] varchar(100),
[Column B] varchar(100),
[Column C] varchar(100)
)
*/
declare @string varchar(max) = 'Apple,Banana,Orange'
select * from dbo.Split(@string, ',')

insert into TableT
select
    MAX([Column A]) as [Column A],
    MAX([Column B]) as [Column B],
    MAX([Column C]) as [Column C]
from (
select
    case when id = 1 then val end as [Column A],
    case when id = 2 then val end as [Column B],
    case when id = 3 then val end as [Column C]
from dbo.Split(@string, ',')
) s

select * from TableT
```

Answer (score -2):

Please make use of the below query. Its working fine in SQL Server 2012.

```
BEGIN
      DECLARE @input VARCHAR(4000)
      DECLARE @str VARCHAR(4000)
      DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(max)
      SET @input ='(Apple,Banana,Orange)'
      IF(@input is not null)
        BEGIN
                SET @str = (SELECT REPLACE(@input,'(','('''))
                SET @str = (SELECT REPLACE(@str,')',''')'))
                SET @str = (SELECT REPLACE(@str,',',''','''))
           SET @Query ='INSERT INTO MyTable (ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC)VALUES '+@str
           Exec (@Query)

        END
END
```

Comment: This is even worst idea then the question. Not only is it error prone, it's also an open door for sql injection attacks.

Comment: @AbinAugustine consider the following input: `'(Apple,Banana,Orange);DROP TABLE MyTable'`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - He mentioned that he is not using the same with front end. So I believe this will help.

Comment: @PraveenND I Don't see any scenario where a security hazard code help anyone except potential hackers.