# Send csv data to stored procedure and insert into #temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I know this is dirty but is there a way to send csv data (carriage return separated) in this exact format:

```
1,2,"Bla1"
3,4,"Bla2"
```

to a stored procedure and insert it into a #temp table.

Skeleton:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM sys.objects
           WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'USP_Test')
    DROP PROCEDURE USP_Test
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE USP_Test
    @CsvData NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #Temp
        (
            Number1 FLOAT,
            Number2 FLOAT, 
            String NVARCHAR(255)
        )

    -- insert @CsvData into #Temp
END
```

I like table-valued parameters for this kind of scenario but I can only control that an `nvarchar` is sent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read string with comma and insert into sql table single row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404919/read-string-with-comma-and-insert-into-sql-table-single-row)

Comment: There is a way, but you will have to be extra careful with the input. at least you know it's dirty...

Comment: With that last column, what happens if there is a quote in the field value? Does it double up? 1,2,"Joe ""The awkward one"" Bloggs"

Comment: @Martin - I just made it csv-ish. It is just an example. I am empowered to prevent ".

Comment: @ZoharPeled the possible duplicate you quote is not applicable in my scenario.

Comment: Can you verify that your input is safe? Do you have a string splitting function or can you create one?

Comment: @ZoharPeled - as I said I cannot but I am aware of this. Could you please make a constructive contribution?

Comment: I would it answer much like gofr1 did. I don't see a point in adding another answer that's basically the same as an existing answer.

Comment: http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm  and why do you say that @ZoharPeled's duplicate is not applicable?   Looks like the same question to me.

Comment: So which one is the correct answer and does it work for several lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it with XML, but if the input data is large there may be performance issues.

```
DECLARE @CsvData nvarchar(max) = 
'1,2,"Bla1"
3,4,"Bla2"
5,6,"Bla3"
7,8,"Bla4"
9,10,"Bla5"
11,12,"Bla6"
13,14,"Bla7"
15,16,"Bla8"
16,18,"Bla9"'

DECLARE @xml xml

SELECT @xml = CAST('<row>' + REPLACE('<s>' + REPLACE(@CsvData,',','</s><s>')+'</s>',CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'</s></row><row><s>') + '</row>' as xml)


SELECT  t.v.value('s[1]','float') as Number1,
        t.v.value('s[2]','float') as Number2,
        t.v.value('s[3]','nvarchar(255)') as String 
FROM @xml.nodes('/row') as t(v)
```

Output:

```
Number1 Number2 String
1       2       "Bla1"
3       4       "Bla2"
5       6       "Bla3"
7       8       "Bla4"
9       10      "Bla5"
11      12      "Bla6"
13      14      "Bla7"
15      16      "Bla8"
16      18      "Bla9"
```